# how to make input width larger and above the plant when focusing it?

Tags: html, css

I want the style of the input element at the top-left of [**github.com**](http://www.github.com). When I click the input `Search or type a command`, the width of the input becomes larger and it will becomes above these elements back.

After doing some searches, I do not find the approach to it. This is what I have tried: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxa5N/3/)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a similar animation, you need to add a transition:

```
#input-text {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    transition: width 100ms ease-in;
}
```

If you want the menu overlaying effect, you can use the below as a strating point:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxa5N/6/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type='text' />
    <ul>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <li>Item3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position:relative;
}
input {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    z-index:1;
    transition:200ms width ease-in;
}
input:focus {
    width:500px;
}
input:focus + ul{
    opacity:0;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:320px;
    z-index:0;
    opacity:1;
    transition:200ms opacity ease-out;
}
ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul, li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this a while ago - specifically the github search bar.

There are loads of articles already out there on how to do this. I would start with them?

http://java.dzone.com/articles/recreate-github-search-box 
http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-a-slide-out-search-box

Comment: Thanks for your links. It can inspire me.

Answer (score 0):

What you want are CSS transitions: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

```
#input-text {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qxa5N/5/